# Can queue trigger in azure send more than one data in one go?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-queues, azure-blob-trigger

My project flow contains-

1. a machine learning container instance which receives some data and return a output.
2. function app for queue trigger.

from queues, data goes to container instance and returns output,then output is stored in a different queue. Now this data flow is happening with FIFO. It is sending one data at a time. It is making my process very slow.
Is there any chance I can send whole queue data in just one go to container instance?
You can provide alternative solution as well.

Answer (score -1):

---

Queue triggers work when a message adds to the queue. Its process FIFO. if you want to send multiple messages or values into a single request in that case you can create an object and send this object. its holds multiples values as show in blew screenshot. but i can't find any document on send multiple queue data on single go.

[image]

[image]